# update value: radio-button values togglig back and forth

Tags: jsf-2

I'm trying to update a a radio-componet, which is triggered by a onchange-event of a select-box. I see the radio-button toggling as desired after the onchange, but it automatically toggles back the next second.

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="selectId" value="#{someBean.someSelectValue}" 
 onchange="this.form.submit()" valueChangeListener="#{someBean.someChange}" immediate="true">
  <p:ajax update="radioId"/>
  <f:selectItems value="#{someBean.availableSraTitel}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>

<h:selectOneRadio id="radioId" value="#{someBean.someRadioValue}">
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Yes" itemValue="true" />
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="No" itemValue="false" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

What am I missing here?

Jonny

Comment: Please don't read JSF 1.x targeted answers/tutorials/books/resources when developing with JSF 2.x.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `onchange="this.form.submit()"` (the `f:ajax` will submit the value to the server)

Also remove `immediate="true"` (I don't think you really planning to skip any validations here)

Last thing,  change `<p:ajax update="radioId"/>` into `<f:ajax render="radioId"/>`

`p:ajax` is from primefaces and you are using plain JSF components

As suggested by **BalusC** : You also better replace the `valueChangeListener="#{someBean.someChange}"` by adding `listener="#{someBean.someChange}"` to your `f:ajax` (you should change teh signature of the method too)

Comment: Although not necessary, I'd prefer to also replace `valueChangeListener` by `<f:ajax listener>`. You're not interested in the old value and `valueChangeListener` will be the wrong place when you intend to change other input's value.